# "Error: Not supported" when caused by `import("react-markdown")`

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, project, react-markdown

I'm trying to import [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown), but I'm getting `Error: Not supported`

```
module.exports = import("react-markdown");
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Can you show the code where you're importing/using `react-markdown`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the react markdown library. In Next.js, you should not export libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing the library first and export it directly (although I don't know why you would want to do that, as you can import it in the file where you're going to use the "exported library").

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'

module.exports = ReactMarkdown
```